# Open another editor from the eclipse search view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a file which can be edited using two different editors.

In eclipses' project explorer you can open a file in a different editor from the context menu.

How can I open a search result (shown in the Search view) in a different editor?

As I am developing an own plug-in, a way to extend the Search view's context menu would be a valid solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' think there is a way to get the search view to use a different editor.

You can contribute to the search view using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point. The view id is `org.eclipse.search.ui.views.SearchView` so something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
 <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.search.ui.views.SearchView">
     <command
           commandId="my.command.id"
           label="Test Search View Contrib"
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Comment: Thank you, greg. There already is a context menu entry called "Show in" - is that one meant to be filled with other possible editors? How would one add an entry to that sub-Menu? Also it is probably not possible to have the entry only depending on the clicked search view entry?

Comment: Show In is to show the file in Views not to open Editors

Comment: Even though the answer is not the desired one (meaning the one I was hoping for), it is the correct one in case of eclipse.